# Does every connected metric space $X$ contains a connected subset $A$ such that $X \setminus A$ is infinite?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Convention : Whenever we are going to talk about connected spaces , we will mean with more than one point .

I am trying to see whether every connected metric space $X$ contains a connected subset $A$ such that $X \setminus A$ is infinite ? Towards this , let $X$ be connected and for some $p\in X$ say if $X \setminus\{p\}$ is not connected , then by [To show that every connected $T_1$ space has a connected proper subset with more than one point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462124/to-show-that-every-connected-t-1-space-has-a-connected-proper-subset-with-more)   , $U \cup\{p\}$ is a connected subset whose compliment is $V$ , and since $V \cup \{p\}$ is also connected , so $V$ is infinite and we are done . So w.l.o.g. . let $X \setminus \{p\}$ is connected for every $p \in X$ and then by applying similar reasoning we can say w.l.o.g. , $X \setminus \{p_1,...,p_n\}$ is connected for every finite subset $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$ of $X$ , but then I am stuck . I am not sure whether the claim I am trying to prove is true or not . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Just take $A$ to be a point, if  $X \setminus A$ would be finite, then $X$ would be discrete, hence since $X$ is connected $X=A$.

Comment: @user60589 : I fixed the convention , please read from the start ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul Erdős attributes to A.Stone the following theorem:

**Theorem.** Every (infinite) connected set $X$ contains a connected subset $Y$ such that $X-Y$ is infinite.

See [here](http://bsmath.hu/~p_erdos/1944-06.pdf) for a proof, p. 443-444. (I think the proof implicitly assumes that $X$ is Hausdorff, but I am not sure.)

Comment: I have read the proof ; I don't understand quite a few things . Is it true that in a connected metric space there always exist sequence of distinct elements converging to an element in that space ? Why are the closed subsets of  $\{p_n:n \in \mathbb N\}$ finite ? And how , if $X \setminus \{p_n:n \in \mathbb N\}$ is not connected then $X \setminus B$ is also not connected for some closed subset $B$ of $\{p_n:n \in \mathbb N\}$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev: I think you just have to spend more time reading his proof. Let me explain the first point, assuming that $X$ is metrizable (which suffices for you). A space $X$ is called perfect if it contains no isolated points. Since $X$ is assumed to be 1st countable, if it is perfect then every point is the limit of a sequence in $X$. Each infinite connected metrizable space has to be perfect.  Erdos observes that it suffices to consider the case when the complement of finite subset is connected. In particular, this complement is perfect. From this, he constructs the required sequence.

Comment: Erdös needs a countable set that is discrete in the subspace topology but not closed (so he uses a convergent sequence minus the limit). In metric spaces we can do this (or first countable spaces, and we can further generalise this). His proof doesn't work in totally general spaces, but in the rest of the paper he talks about subspaces of Euclidean spaces, so he presumably means this in this context.